# Full width issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

[image]For some reason the image I had on my site has stopped being full width.

From what I can see everything is set to a 100% width.

http://cargocollective.com/btatest

Have I noob'd up somewhere?

Comment: Me too! What browser you using? Tried the old Ctrl-f5?

Comment: why is background-size: 110%;?

Comment: why is there a margin-left and margin right of -50%?

Comment: margins are -50% because that background is inside project container, and he wants to background exceed over that container.

Comment: with background-size: 110%; image is zoomed. put background-size: 100%; to get 100% width

Comment: How did you assume that `720px + -50% + -50%` should become 100%? If you need something full width you should set it to a width of 100%, and not 720px…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need to change a bit of your html code.

Try to avoid negative margins by doing this:

Set `width: 100%;` to `id="content_container"`, `id="maincontainer"` and `class="entry"`. Set any width you want to `class="project_content"` (recommended - less than 1000px). And then remove `class="social"`(which contains background) from `class="project_content"`. `Set width: 100%` `in class="social"`.

There is a lot of changes, so i can't describe it all. I've changed your js, and some of css and html. You will see. Here is your code, just copy from here and test it. Here is not nice preview, but copy code in your editor. It looks fine now. http://jsfiddle.net/BsJsk/

Comment: got a bit lost there. I'll update my original post with the content as it stands.

Comment: Thanks @miljanpuzovic this has resolved the scrolling issue. But the image is no longer 100% width.

Comment: you didn't copied code, i don't see some changes on live site that i maked in jsfiddle.

Comment: @user1522319 please, just copy that code (both html and css), don't change anything, and we will see what happens.

Comment: I other words - save your code in some backup files, and then use ONLY code from my jsfiddle.

Comment: to some extent that worked. However, I'm running my site on Cargo Collective – which is a CMS. Currently the script, type kit etc go into a HTML document, then the pictures and text go into separate project pages. Sooooo, did you edit the Jquery I pasted above or edit the CSS or edited the social div? Then I can see if there's a workaround. Thanks Michael

Comment: i've edited js for .social, css (renamed content_container into content-container) and html (moved .social from .project_content). I've opened your link just now, it looks ok now. You made changes i've suggested?

Comment: it looks ok as a page, but adding all of the HTML prevents the CMS from working. If I try and add another project it overrides it and causes problems. Essentially I need to know the changes to the social script and the changes to the CSS.

Comment: ok, open jsfiddle link and follow me: in social script, i've added var socalDivWidth = 100;, removed 'margin-left' : '-100%', and 'margin-right' : '-100%', changed 'background-size' : '110% auto', to 'background-size' : '100% auto', and added line 'width' : socalDivWidth + '%'. 

In CSS, add "width:100%" to id="content_container", id="maincontainer" and  class="entry". Rename id="content_container" into "content-container" an change that new name in html (or you can do this over your CMS if you must).

In HTML, move <div class="social"></div> out from <div class="project_content">

Comment: I've just updated my script – I copy and pasted your JSFiddle. As you can see the image is no longer full width

Comment: Ah – I see the problem now. I can't remove the social div from the project_content. If you look at my updated post (above) you'll see how I add things to my site. You'll see the social div in the bottom left box. When you click 'post' it sets it within the project_content div automatically.

Comment: Yes, i can see... I didn't know from the start that you can add content only from CMS. If you can change CMS, that would be nice :)

Comment: I've found a workaround. I add the whole div to my html, then in project editor I hide the div. So this is with it showing: http://cargocollective.com/btatest and this is with it hiding: http://cargocollective.com/btatest/Untitled-project Job done I think! Thanks Miljan

Comment: That is it! Image looks fine, and have width:100% always. Just, #content_container still have width:1088px, and because of that, content is a bit moved to left side. To center whole content below image, you must find a way to set width:100% on #content_container.

Comment: You can change width of #content_container to 100% or you can just add to him margin:0 auto;

Comment: That could be done with setting the content_container: left: 50%; margin-left: 200px; (need to play with that number), instead of: margin 0 auto;.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```css
margin-left: -50%;
margin-right: -50%;
```

to:

```css
margin-left: -100%;
margin-right: -100%;
```

### Before:

> [image]

### After:

> [image]

Comment: I'm getting from beginning preview like on yours "After" image. And with margins -100% it's just bigger scrollbar.

Comment: @MiljanPuzović Then it's probably the browser issue. I'm on FF 14.

Comment: Probably. I'm on Chrome. But i opened that site also from ff 14 and it's fine, full width.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm viewing it on Safari and Firefox. To @MiljanPuzović point there seems to be a bit of excessive horizontal scrolling, any idea why that is?